# How To Send Dictionary Data as Email via SMTPLib?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, smtplib

I have a list with multiple dictionaries in it.

```
items = [{'title':'example', 'link':'example.com'}, {'title': 'example2', 'link':'example.com'}]
```

I want to include this data in email. Via email.message library.

How do I include the above data in one email?

`msg.set_content('I want to include some keys here. Like: Title items['title'] ')`.

I want all of values with 'title' key in the email body.

The email template should be like this:

> Hello,
>
> Here is the
>
> link: {link}
>
> Title: {title}
>
> Price {price}
> ---------- 2nd product
>
> link: {link}
>
> Title: {title}
>
> Price {price}

Please note, all the data is available in list and dictionaries as items in it. And dictionaries have the data I want.

How do I do it?

Thank you